# How to calculate the probability in the event that a number is not the one from the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, probability

I have a list:

```
lst = [10,20,39,50]
```

How to calculate the probability in Python that a number picked up from the list is not 10? (An event can be supposed)

Comment: `1 - 1/len(lst)` assumed independence

Comment: In general, P(not A) = 1 - P(A) where A is any proposition. In this case A = "number picked is 10". Now as to what is P(A), that depends on specific data and assumptions for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of getting 10 from the list is just the number of times 10 appears on the list over the length of the list:

```
p10 = lst.count(10) / len(lst)
```

Whereas the probability of NOT getting a 10 is just the complement:

```
p_not10 = 1 - p10
```